# What Pay-in lounges are there at Stockholm Arlanda Airport?

Tags: sweden, lounges, airport-terminals

I'll be flying from Stockholm Arlanda Airport and my ticket doesn't include lounge access. What lounges accept payment for access at Arlanda Airport?

I've found Arlanda Lounge and Menzies but not in which terminals they are neither how much they charge or what they offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this link should help: http://www.sleepinginairports.net/airport-lounges/stockholm-arlanda-airport/index.htm

It states the two that you have mentioned as being the only pay-for lounges in ARN, both in Terminal 5, and when clicking through the 'buy a lounge pass' options, it comes out at 'from £22' for adult access.

[image]